# How do you enable syntax highlighting in visual studio 2015?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

In VS2013 when I selected a word or letter or number etc... I would get a purple highlight throughout my file.

The first image is an example of VS2013 code highlighting:
[image: VS2013 Screenshot]

This image is the same code selected in VS2015 with out the additional highlighting:

[image: VS2015 Screenshot]

As you can see from the first image, when the function keyword is selected, ALL of them get highlighted. Unlike the second image of VS2015.

My questions are:

1. Has this been removed in VS2015?
2. What settings do I need to enable to get this function in VS2015 or what addon needs to be installed?

Comment: As you sure in the first example you don't have a plugin installed?

Answer (score 2):

I forgot about the addons. Its the Productivity Power Tools found here: [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)